# scrollTo.js Unexpected number

Tags: jquery, navigation, scrollto

Hi everyone i want make a nav with scroll but i have this error:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number

```
 $('.nav-link').on('click',function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            scrollTo($(this).attr('href') 200 );
        })


  });
```

Comment: `$(this).attr('href') 200 ` is incorrect. What exactly do you want to scrollTo ?

Comment: You're missing a , after `.attr('href')`

Comment: try this  $(('.nav-link').ScrollTo();

Answer (score 0):

Correct syntax of scrollTo is:

```
window.scrollTo(xpos,ypos)
```

Your code should be:

```
 $('.nav-link').on('click',function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            scrollTo(300, 200 ); // as per correct syntax

        });
```

But, if you want to scroll to any element, read this answer: [jQuery scroll to element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677035/jquery-scroll-to-element)

Also, as you have mentioned that you are using **scrollTo.js** plugin,
Your code should be:

```
   $('.nav-link').on('click',function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                $('#<ID_OF_ELEMENT>').ScrollTo();     

            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be trying to use [jquery.scrollTo](https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo) albeit incorrectly.

First make you sure include jQuery (1.8 or above) and also jquery.scrollTo (2.1.0), something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.scrollto/2.1.0/jquery.scrollTo.min.js"></script>
```

then add this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.nav-link').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(window).stop(true).scrollTo(this.hash, {duration:200, interrupt:true});
  });
});
</script>
```

That works. 200 seems too fast but you can tweak it to your liking.